# Android EspressoTest match navigationDrawer item with position

Tags: android, android-espresso

I want to open navigation drawer and click specific position item with code as below.

```
private void clickMenu(int position) {
    onView(withId(R.id.drawer_layout))
            .perform(actionOpenDrawer());

    onData(is(instanceOf(NavDrawerItem.class)))
            .inAdapterView(withId(R.id.navigation_list))
            .atPosition(position).perform(ViewActions.click());
}
```

Current it shows no matches.

```
android.support.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: with id: com.trumpia.android.loyaltea.debug:id/navigation_list
If the target view is not part of the view hierarchy, you may need to use Espresso.onData to load it from one of the following AdapterViews:android.widget.ListView{3bb66aad VFED.VC. .F...... 0,0-720,1533 #7f0f008c app:id/navigation_drawer}
- android.widget.ListView{22585c25 GFED.VC. ......I. 0,0-0,0 #102000a android:id/list}
```

or other error as below

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Action will not be performed because the target view does not match one or more of the following constraints:
(is assignable from class: class android.widget.AdapterView and is displayed on the screen to the user)
Target view: "ListView{id=2131689612, res-name=navigation_drawer, visibility=INVISIBLE, width=720, height=1533, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=-720.0, y=0.0, child-count=5}"
```

It seems there some inconsistent between each running.
Is this because drawer is not fully opened? How can I guarantee that drawer is opened?

If I comment .inAdapterView line then, it matches two item like as below.

```
+--------->ListView{id=16908298, res-name=list, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=0} ****MATCHES****
...
+------>ListView{id=2131689612, res-name=navigation_drawer, visibility=VISIBLE, width=720, height=1533, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=true, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=-1.0, y=0.0, child-count=5} ****MATCHES****
```

Is there any good way to match navigation drawer item by item position?
I can match with text but the item order is matter in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I changed `AdapterView`'s resource name to `R.id.navigation_drawer` from `R.id.navigation_list`. and update espresso core to 2.2 from 2.0, then it works well.

```
private void clickMenu(int position) {
    onView(withId(R.id.drawer_layout))
            .perform(actionOpenDrawer()); 

    onData(is(instanceOf(NavDrawerItem.class))) 
            .inAdapterView(withId(R.id.navigation_drawer))
            .atPosition(position).perform(ViewActions.click());
}
```

`NavigationDrawerFragment` replaced into `R.id.navigation_drawer` fragment MainActivity.
And `NavigationDrawerFragment` has only `R.id.navigation_list` `ListView`.